# gitlab push is asking for github credentials?

Tags: github, terminal, gitlab

I'm trying to push some files to a Gitlab project which I've already created in the GitLab GUI.  So I'm trying to add some files to that project which already exists.

When I try:

```
git remote add origin https://git.doit.wisc.edu/my_user_name/my-website.git
```

I get this error:

```
error: remote origin already exists.
```

So I figured I could move on to the next step in the documentation - `git branch.`

Then I use:

```
git branch -M main
```

I was prompted with:

[image]

I entered my keychain password and all seemed fine but when I try to do:

```
git push -uf origin main
```

The terminal reads:

```
Username for 'https://github.com':
```

I put in my username and then get this error:

```
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.
remote: Please see https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for information on currently recommended modes of authentication.
```

It seems like git is confusing gitlab and github.  I'm trying to push to gitlab, not github.  I'm so confused here. Is there something I'm missing in the first step?

Answer (score 1):

No, Git's not confused here.  When you said, `git remote add origin…` and Git reported an error, that means that the remote `origin` already exists for that repository.  In this case, that remote points somewhere on GitHub, which you can see with `git remote -v`.

If you want to replace the existing URL for the `origin` remote, use `git remote set-url origin https://git.doit.wisc.edu/my_user_name/my-website.git`.  If you want to create a new, differently named remote, then do `git remote add gitlab https://git.doit.wisc.edu/my_user_name/my-website.git` and push with `git push gitlab main`.

Note also that GitHub no longer allows you to use your account password to authenticate with Git.  Instead, when prompted for a password, go to https://github.com/settings/tokens and create a token with the `repo` scope, and use that instead.  However, in this case, since you're intending to push to GitLab, that shouldn't matter here.